# Can a numpy file be created without defining an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have some very large data to deal with. I'd like to be able to use `np.load(filename, mmap_mode="r+")` to use these files on disk rather than RAM. My issue is that creating them in RAM causes the exact problem I'm trying to avoid.

I know about `np.memmap` already and that is a potential solution, but creating a memmap and then saving the array using `np.save(filename, memmap)` means that I'd be doubling the disk space requirement even if only briefly and that isn't always an option. Primarily I don't want to use memmaps because the header information in `.npy` files (namely shape and dtype) is useful to have.

My question is, can I create a numpy file without needing to first create it in memory? That is, can I create a numpy file by just giving a dtype and a shape? The idea would be along the lines of `np.save(filename, np.empty((x, y, z)))` but I'm assuming that empty requires it to be assigned in memory before saving.

My current solution is:

```py
def create_empty_numpy_file(filename, shape, dtype=np.float64):
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmp:
        memmap = np.memmap(tmp, dtype, mode="w+", shape=shape)
        np.save(filename, memmap)
```

---

**EDIT**

My final solution based on bnaeker's answer and a few details from numpy.lib.format:

```py
class MockFlags:
    def __init__(self, shape, c_contiguous=True):
        self.c_contiguous = c_contiguous
        self.f_contiguous = (not c_contiguous) or (c_contiguous and len(shape) == 1)


class MockArray:
    def __init__(self, shape, dtype=np.float64, c_contiguous=True):
        self.shape = shape
        self.dtype = np.dtype(dtype)
        self.flags = MockFlags(shape, c_contiguous)

    def save(self, filename):
        if self.dtype.itemsize == 0:
            buffersize = 0
        else:
            # Set buffer size to 16 MiB to hide the Python loop overhead.
            buffersize = max(16 * 1024 ** 2 // self.dtype.itemsize, 1)

        n_chunks, remainder = np.divmod(
            np.product(self.shape) * self.dtype.itemsize, buffersize
        )

        with open(filename, "wb") as f:
            np.lib.format.write_array_header_2_0(
                f, np.lib.format.header_data_from_array_1_0(self)
            )

            for chunk in range(n_chunks):
                f.write(b"\x00" * buffersize)
            f.write(b"\x00" * remainder)
```

Comment: Is the data already stored in a file in some binary format?

Comment: No, the data is going to be calculated on the fly. I know the shape and dtype in advance but not the content.

Comment: `mmap_mode` is only an option for `np.load`, not for `np.save`.

Comment: Apart from the header, a `npy` file is just a byte copy of the array's data buffer.

Comment: @hpaulj I'm creating a lot of files with varying dimensions, hence why I don't want to have to track that information separately. The headers are a key part of this for me which is why I mentioned them in the question

Comment: `h5py` is another way of saving and accessing arrays by slice.  I don't know how speed compares `mmap`.  Probably slower due to more overhead.

Comment: Have you considered using a netCDF file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Numpy file format is [really simple](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.html). There are a few under-documented functions you can use to create the required header bytes from the *metadata* needed to build an array, without actually building one.

```py
import numpy as np

def create_npy_header_bytes(
    shape, dtype=np.float64, fortran_order=False, format_version="2.0"
):
    # 4 or 2-byte unsigned integer, depending on version
    n_size_bytes = 4 if format_version[0] == "2" else 2
    magic = b"\x93NUMPY"
    version_info = (
        int(each).to_bytes(1, "little") for each in format_version.split(".")
    )

    # Keys are supposed to be alphabetically sorted
    header = {
        "descr": np.lib.format.dtype_to_descr(np.dtype(dtype)),
        "fortran_order": fortran_order,
        "shape": shape
    }

    # Pad header up to multiple of 64 bytes
    header_bytes = str(header).encode("ascii")
    header_len = len(header_bytes)
    current_length = header_len + len(magic) + 2 + n_size_bytes  # for version information
    required_length = int(np.ceil(current_length / 64.0) * 64)
    padding = required_length - current_length - 1  # For newline
    header_bytes += b" " * padding + b"\n"

    # Length of the header dict, including padding and newline
    length = len(header_bytes).to_bytes(n_size_bytes, "little")

    return b"".join((magic, *version_info, length, header_bytes))
```

You can test that it's equivalent with this snippet:

```py
import numpy as np
import io
x = np.zeros((10, 3, 4))

first = create_npy_header_bytes(x.shape)
stream = io.BytesIO()
np.lib.format.write_array_header_2_0(
    stream, np.lib.format.header_data_from_array_1_0(x)
)
print(f"Library: {stream.getvalue()}")
print(f"Custom: {first}")
```

You should see something like:

```py
Library: b"\x93NUMPY\x02\x00t\x00\x00\x00{'descr': '<f8', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (10, 3, 4), }                                                    \n"
Custom: b"\x93NUMPY\x02\x00t\x00\x00\x00{'descr': '<f8', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (10, 3, 4)}                                                      \n"
```

which match, except for the trailing comma inside the header dict representation. That will not matter, as this is required to be a valid Python literal string representation of a dict, which will happily ignore that comma if it's there.

---

As an alternative approach, you could *mock out* an object which has the required fields for the library functions used to make the header itself. For `np.lib.format.header_data_from_array_1_0`, these seem to be `.flags` (which must have a field `c_contiguous` and/or `f_contiguous`), and a `dtype`. That's actually much simpler, and would look like:

```py
import numpy as np
import io

class MockFlags:
    def __init__(self, shape, c_contiguous=True):
        self.c_contiguous = c_contiguous
        self.f_contiguous = (not c_contiguous) or (c_contiguous and len(shape) == 1)

class MockArray:
    def __init__(self, shape, dtype=np.float64, c_contiguous=True):
        self.shape = shape
        self.dtype = np.dtype(dtype)
        self.flags = MockFlags(shape, c_contiguous)

mock = MockArray((10, 3, 4))
stream = io.BytesIO()
np.lib.format.write_array_header_2_0(
    stream, np.lib.format.header_data_from_array_1_0(mock)
)
print(stream.getvalue())
```

You should see:

```
b"\x93NUMPY\x02\x00t\x00\x00\x00{'descr': '<f8', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (10, 3, 4), }                                                    \n"
```

which happily matches what we have above, but without having to do the shitty work of counting bytes, mucking with padding, etc. Much more betterer :)

Comment: This is an incredible answer. Thanks so much!